# Separate code to main and test branches under `src` folder without changing packages names

Tags: java, apache, project, package, directory-structure

I would like to adopt an [Apache Software Foundation's standard directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) to already existing project, which is:

```
module/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        com.mycompany...
    test/
      java/
        com.mycompany...
```

The issue is that after moving the sources from `src/com.mycompany`to `src/main/java/com.mycompany` and `src/test/java/com.mycompany` the IDE (Eclipse) returns a warning and proposes to rename the packages from `com.mycompany` to `main.java.com.mycompany` and `test.java.com.mycompany` respectively.

**Important note:**
Since this is a legacy project without any Maven integration, but which is still in use in production, I would like to reduce a changes to the project as much as possible but still separate the code on production and unit test code.

Is there any way to avoid packages renaming in all source-files but still to use Apache's source directory structure?

Comment: This is because now not `src` but `main` and `test` are the java source folders. I personally would switch to the **maven** convention, start wit a maven project: src/main/java and src/test/java and likewise src/main/resources and src/test/resources. Maven already is well integrated in all IDEs. For now set the source folders in eclipse appropriately (or make a maven project).

Comment: @JoopEggen, do I understand it correctly that in order specify a new java source folder I have to define `pom.xml`?

Comment: Yes, as: File / New > / Project ... / Maven / Maven Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the pom.xml but you can also edit the project in Eclipse and define the source folders there

I noticed you actually misread the Apache standard structure, it follows the Maven convention `src/main/java` etc so I would use that. Then, if you use some form of Maven-Eclipse integration the source folders should automatically be set correctly by default. I used to do that with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (using the eclipse-maven-plugin) but that's a long time ago - I use Intellij now. I'm guessing by now Eclipse picks up the source path from Maven automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since this specific project is kind of legacy code without any Maven integration, which is still in use in production, I would like to reduce a changes to just some settings in `pom.xml` without adding Maven integration it self.

Comment: Maven integration is only something you need if you want this to be picked up automatically in Eclipse. To make the Maven build work, you just need to put your source in the default locations (`src/main/java` for example) and the build will pick it up if you run for example `mvn clean install` on the command line in the project root dir.